# UnityPerRequestHttpModule for WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Is there any equivalent to the:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

Found in the Unity Mvc Bootstrap but for the WebApi Boostrap?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, [Unity.WebAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/) nuget package + registering the services with `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you installed unofficial version of Unity. Consider removing your previous Unity related packages and install this one:

```
Install-Package Unity.AspNet.WebApi
```